# How to use file logger in react-native app

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to write logs to file from RN app.
I want to use files for a few reasons:

1. QA/debugging - I send the app to QA/other developers. In case of an error, I want them to send me the file, so I will understand what is the issue.
2. On production, I might want to send the log file to the server on specific scenarios (critical bugs).

I don't mind asking for storage permission since I need it anyway (for other features).
It's very strange that I didn't find any package for it. 
I expect to have something like log4j/logback, including rolling file, log levels, etc. Is there any package that can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[react-native-file-log](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-log) is a good choice. It can log messages to files.

Usage:

```
import RNReactLogging from 'react-native-file-log';

RNReactLogging.setTag('MyAppName'); // default: RNReactLogging
RNReactLogging.setConsoleLogEnabled(false); // default: true
RNReactLogging.setFileLogEnabled(true); // default: false
RNReactLogging.setMaxFileSize(1024 * 1024); // default: 512 * 1024 ~ 512 kb
RNReactLogging.printLog('test log');
```

Also check [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com/error-tracking/react-native/) which is a realtime crash and error logging solution.

Comment: Thanks ! react-native-file-log has only 2 stars on github - why ? I wonder why file logging is not common on RN apps.

Comment: Ya. There is only a few stars for that repo. And only 22 weekly downloads. But the scenario is rare. Logging is mainly used only at development phase.